# Is there a proper way to nest git repos?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gruntjs, gulp

I manage a few gulp/grunt based sites that use sass/scss.  I always set up a git repo for the project folder with the src files and other non "front-end" files.  I have been looking for a way to have a separate "dist" repo inside the main repo.  For instance:

```
- Project Folder (main git repo)
--.bowerrc
--bower.json
--gulp.js
:
:
--Dist folder (dist repo)
----index.html
----CSS
----IMG
:
:
--other folder etc..
```

I have intermediate experience with git and it seem like this may be able to be done with branching.

My goal is the have the "list repo/branch" files in a gh-pages branch for temp hosting.

Comment: https://github.com/shinnn/gulp-gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

Don't create nested repos for build/dist files. Automate publishing from the sources:

Create a script that builds (minify, bundle, etc.) your project and then pushes the result to the `gh-pages` branch on Github.